Please reach out to Replit regarding outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow
We have another company using Stack Overflow as outsourced customer support. This time, it's Replit.
There seems to have been as redesign of the site and recent shut down of their community support forum, and in doing so, there has been a surge of off-topic customer support questions going through the Staging Ground.
The source of this seems to be the Get Help popup available from the dashboard (requires login) in the top-right of the site and by visiting https://replit.com/support while logged in. As far as I can see, they do not make an effort to link to any other source of support other than a "community hub" with no community-facing forum or chat. Almost all of the options available in this popup improperly encourage posting to Stack Overflow, including:

I found a bug

To report a bug, please post to Stack Overflow.

(This is not acceptable. Why does the Stack Overflow community care about Replit bugs? This option links to the New Question page with a very unhelpful default title, "I found a bug")

I need help with my code

If you are stuck on a problem with your code, please post on Stack Overflow for help. If you want a major feature implemented in your project, you can create a Bounty.

(This option is mostly fine, but it includes a button to the New Question page with a not-very-useful default title of "I need help with my code" and the tags replit and code-help. In this context, "Bounty" refers to Replit's version of bounties, where people can implement code for a monetary reward)

I would like to request a new feature

We love new ideas! If you have one, make a post on Stack Overflow to share your idea with the community and the Replit team.

(This is definitely not okay and should not be directed to Stack Overflow. It includes a button to the New Question page with a default title of "I would like to request a new feature" and a tags replit and feature-request)

I need help using Replit

If you are unsure how to use a certain feature or want to ask a general question about Replit, create a post on Stack Overflow. Please provide as much detail as possible so that your question can be addressed quickly.

(This one is also mostly okay, it could use a bit more emphasis on making the questions specific and answerable, but questions about using Replit are on-topic. This links to the New Question page with a default title of "I need help using Replit" and the tags replit and replit-help)

I have an account issue
(This includes a link to the New Question page without any context, with an extremely unhelpful default title of "I have an account issue" and tags replit and account-issue. There is a separate set of options presented about changing emails and usernames, and another option that links to Stack Overflow)

My repl isn't loading

Please make a post on Stack Overflow and include the link to your Repl.

(Depending on the context, this is probably okay. Code errors? Probably fine. Problems with Replit itself? Definitely not. This links to the New Question page with a default title of "My repl isn't loading" and tags replit and repl-not-loading)


I will note that they do have an email support option, but it's not mentioned at all in the Get Help popup or the Support page which shows for not logged in users, and is buried in the documentation in a very not obvious legal and security section. Could someone at Stack Overflow please reach out to Replit to let them know that directing non-technical support questions to here is not okay?

It should be noted that these auxiliary tags (other than [tag:replit]) don't exist on SO, so new users won't be able to post questions with these tags anyway!

A link the the relevant FAQ post would not a bad thing to provide the Replit team.

It gets worse, going to https://replit.com/support while logged in brings up the same Get Help popup, and their "community hub" has no community forum or chat, just some links to example projects, socials, and - of course - Stack Overflow. Looks like they've replaced their entire community support with outsourcing to here!

Wow, so... They're obviously showing something very different to logged-in users than what I was able to see when I looked into it as someone without a Replit account when that question you linked was posted on MSE. My reaction would have been very different if I'd seen anything remotely close to what you're quoting here, explicitly stating that bug reports or feature requests should be posted on Stack Overflow. That's just on-face absurd.

It doesn't appear the public guidance has changed from when I looked into it, either. Their "Community Hub" has a section entitled "Connect", where they link to Twitter, YouTube, etc., including SO. There, they say: "Get help from experienced developers on Stack Overflow", which is reasonable. And "Help" still looks the same as the screenshot in my answer. None of those link directly to SO (only indirectly via "Community Hub", which isn't misleading). They also have https://support.replit.com/hc/en-us, but, again, nothing about SO.

Examples: I would like to request a feature about Arduino programming, DISCLAMER: This message is related to an automatic redirect from Replit for sending feedback and suggestions./Please don't close it, i hope replit make replit ai and replit browse unlimited to free useres. And there are also many low-quality questions that, while arguably on-topic, are nowhere near meeting our standards.

These links are probably the results of a search-and-replace that simply changed "Replit Forum" to "Stack Overflow" without any kind of consideration.

Super related: Help center for Can I support my product on this site?.

This is fully ok. Stack Overflow mainly participates from volunteers doing work for free, why shouldn't replit do the same? No objections.

@Ctx This would be an easier argument to stomach if this wasn't a service you had to pay to use for longer than 10 hours a month. Additionally, providing support via Stack Overflow is totally fine, as long as it's being done properly. It's very much not being done properly in this case.

@Ctx No, it's not. Replit's current support strategy essentially boils down to "if you have any questions about Replit, please direct them to Stack Overflow." That's just asking for a flood of low-quality, off-topic questions. At the very least, they need to be linking to the Help Center - and really, they shouldn't be doing this at all.

@Ctx They're explicitly telling people to post off-topic questions (such as feature requests for their platform) on Stack Overflow, thus wasting volunteers' time.  Why is that okay?

Seems nothing has changed after six weeks. I found two "I would like to request a feature" questions in the Staging ground today.

@jps Yep, can confirm that the Get Help options haven't changed at all.

This is, shockingly, still an issue. The content described above remains unchanged, directing Replit users to Stack Overflow to lodge feature requests. Has anyone from CM actually picked up the phone and talked to someone about this?

@esqew Much too busy working on AI answer bots, I'm afraid.
